# Div width and textarea alignment and expand to parent (responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following list in html:

```
<style>
    .right { display: inline-block; }
</style>

<ul class="no-bullets-list">
    <li>
    <div class="list-item">
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
    <img src="image-URL"/>
    <div class="right">
            <input type="text"/>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to show this elements like the image (sorry for the image by the way :))

[image]
The problem I'm having is that the div with the class="right" do not expand to the size of the parent and in consequence the textarea do not grow accordingly.
I need to be able to resize responsively so the div and the textarea have to response in consecuence.

Any ideas? I'm able to use bootstrap so if someone have a solution using it.

Thanks

Comment: Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/EaNzU/) to get you started.

Comment: Woh Woh Woh! @Vucko that's a very very big style. :P

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I used [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) :)

Comment: @Vucko, nice job putting things together, plus the OP can reset what "they need" to reset.  Doesn't have to be everything in the fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

A textarea's height and width are determined by their 'row' and 'column' values. These are static values so they don't change based on the device viewing them. You could look into javascript solutions but its probably more effort than its worth. Just my two cents. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea